# Zend Framework 2 - TemplatePathStack for several entities in module

Tags: php, zend-framework2, directory-structure, zend-view

A while ago I followed the `tutorial` and included the `TemplatePathStack` like it is described [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/modules.html#configuration).

The tutorial suggests for the view directory a structure like `view/album/album` in which all the phtml-files lie.

I wonder what's the reason for album/album... And what if my module is named `MasterData` and it included add/edit/delete... for `Entity1` and `Entity2`.

How does the framework know which add.phtml to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wondering if you're not confusing the entities with the controllers.
Make sure you're following the module directory structure conventions that is summarized (including only what is relevant to your question) as follows:

```
/module
|--/MasterData
|----/src
|--------/Controller
|-----------/Entity1Controller
|-----------/Entity2Controller
|--------/Model
|-----------/Entity1
|-----------/Entity2
|----/view
|------/master-data
|--------/entity1
|-----------/action1.phtml
|-----------/action2.phtml
|--------/entity2
|-----------/action1.phtml
|-----------/action2.phtml
...
```

For the template path stack, and under the previous structure, the configuration is simply:

```
'view_manager' => array(
      'template_path_stack' => array(
           __DIR__ . '/../view',
       ),
),
```

Remember, under the view folder the default convention:

- entity1 is mapped to your Entity1Controller (in case your controller is camelCased, eg: `MyFooController`, the corresponding folder name would be `my-foo`)
- action1.phtml is mapped to the `action1Action` method of your `Entity1Controller` class (same remark as above if your action name is camelcased).

Comment: dumbest mistake ever! I didn't know that you put a minus in `MasterData` when writing it in lowercase! thanks :)